Calling Python Api from javascript file not working
While trying to retrieve data from the python api i created below, i get 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)' error line 3 of the js file. I tried restarting and going through the process again but that resulted in the same thing.
app.js
/*async function fetchdata(){*/
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/get_data');
        const data = await response.json();  // Convert response to JSON

        console.log('Data:', data);

        // return data; 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
/*}
fetchdata();*/

app.py
@app.route('/api/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    form = loginForm()
    print('hello')
    data = {
        "ownsPython": str(User.query.filter_by(username = form.username.data).first().javascriptOwner),
        "ownsJava" : str(User.query.filter_by(username = form.username.data).first().pythonOwner),
        "ownsPython" : str(User.query.filter_by(username = form.username.data).first().ownsJavascript)
    }
    return jsonify(data)


the error is occurring on the server

most useful information will be in the logs of your Flask application. Look for any errors or stack traces printed there when you make the request. This will help you pinpoint the problem.
Potential Causes

loginForm instance and its usage are not shown in your code snippet. Ensure that loginForm is defined correctly and that form.username.data is valid.
form.username.data is not being set properly or User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first() returns None, you'll get an AttributeError when trying to access attributes of None.
have two keys with the same name "ownsPython" in your data dictionary. You should use unique keys.

@app.route('/api/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    try:
        form = loginForm()  
        username = form.username.data
        
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user is None:
            raise ValueError("User not found")
        
        data = {
            "ownsPython": str(user.pythonOwner),
            "ownsJava": str(user.javaOwner),  # Fixed key
            "ownsJavascript": str(user.ownsJavascript)
        }
        
        return jsonify(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        return jsonify({"error": "Internal Server Error"}), 500


cors issue (usual)

you might need to configure CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in your Flask app.
pip install flask-cors

from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

aaand testing :)
Postman or wget or curl to directly test your API endpoint (http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/get_data) and see if it returns the expected result or error.
